# Clean up commit history but keep some commit

Tags: git, github

So guys I've tried to clean up my commit history, which contains old commits, I've tried clean up with `git rebase -i` but no luck (Log history still exist/messy). So I have examples like these

```
09axxx Old commit
09bxxx Old commit
09cxxx Old commit
09dxxx New commit
09exxx New commit
09fxxx New commit
```

after `git rebase -i`

still got these history commits

```
09axxx Old commit
09bxxx Old commit
09cxxx Old commit
09dxxx New commit
09exxx New commit
09fxxx New commit
```

I want to remove those old commits but keep the new commits,hope you can help me guys, Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to describe a bit beyond "no luck" I'm afraid...

Comment: How did you edit the sequence during the rebase? (in the editor)

Comment: II haven't done anything during rebase, because I'm confused and afraid to do it

Comment: create another branch and then experiment on that branch. Once you are sure that you hace acheived what u want, ddo the same steps on ur required branch. Or delete ur requried branch and cut from the branch u experimented on.

Comment: You said: "I've tried clean up with git rebase -i"... and also: "but no luck" ... and in a comment: "II haven't done anything during rebase, because I'm confused and afraid to do it". Imagine if you had luck and it did work... that would be some cool mind reading functionality! Hehe. I think what you meant to ask is ["How do I interactive rebase?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+interactive+rebase)

Comment: Thanks guys, solved by tried create a new branch for experiment

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have these commits:

```
0000A // latest commit
0000B
0000C // You want to delete it
0000D // You want to delete it
0000E // You want to delete it
0000F
0000G // oldest commit
```

Run: `git rebase -i 0000E^` or `git rebase -i 0000F`

After running above command, you must `fixup` or `sqash` the commits you want to be deleted (in this example containts `0000C`, `0000D` and `0000E` commits). At the end, you will have a history like it:

```
0000A
0000B
0000F
0000G
```

All the changes of `0000C`, `0000D` and `0000E` has been applied on the commit `0000F`.

You can see the changes of commit `0000F` by `git show 0000F` to be sure about the changes.